# What should I do as power button do (turn off screen, lock keyboard)?

Tags: android

My goal is make same thing as power button do.
I try PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and this is my code..

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire();
```

after that I open WAKE_LOCK permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

But when I launch my application not thing happen.
Do I miss something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I'm not totally sure whether you:

1. Try to turn off the device by pressing a button
2. Want to make sure the device will not go to sleep (as this is what a `WakeLock` is supposed to help you with). It can't prevent user interaction though (just tested on HTC Desire).

For 1) You can't lock the device or turn it's power off without being signed as a system app, as written here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/36399f15724ac3ae/98d93e53616cf495?show_docid=98d93e53616cf495

For 2) You can prevent the device from sleeping using `WakeLock`, sample code can read like this:

```
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
}

// Call me from a button
public void doLock(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Lock");

    if (!wl.isHeld()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "acquire");
        wl.acquire();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "release");
        wl.release();
    }
}
```